# Gruntfile.js that only uglifies changed file

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to set up a Gruntfile.js that only uglifies the file that has just been changed. I've adapted some of this from the question and answer given at

[How to uglify only changed file with Grunt.js watch task if dynamic expansion in Uglify has been enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836076/how-to-uglify-only-changed-file-with-grunt-js-watch-task-if-dynamic-expansion-in)

As I've understood this, an event should be triggered on watch events, which will then change the uglify task `src` to be the current file path. However GruntJS still uglifies all files, rather than only the one that was just changed.

I'm not sure if I've simply misunderstood the way GruntJS works here, but can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong?

```
var productionPath = "production", devPath = "dev";

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        uglify: {
            options: {
                banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
            },
            build: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: devPath + '/js/',
                src: ['**/*.js'],
                dest: productionPath + '/js/',
                ext: '.min.js'
            }
        },
        watch: {
            options: { spawn: false },
            scripts: {
                files: [devPath + '/**/*.js'],
                tasks: ['uglify']
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify', 'watch']);

    grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath, target) {
        grunt.config('uglify.build.src', filepath);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do yourself a favor, in this case using [grunt-newer](https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-newer) which lets you do what you want very easily.

In theory, you should be able to register a regular `uglify` task and target, and then simply prepend `newer` to it.

```
grunt.registerTask('build', ['newer:uglify:something']);
```

Or simply in the command-line

```
grunt newer:uglify:something
```